# How to declare a compile time constant function in C#

Tags: c#, compilation, constants, constexpr

In C++, we can use macro or constexpr (as C++11 said). What can we do in C#?

Please see "Cannot declare..." comment for context:

```
static class Constant
{
    // we must ensure this is compile time const, have to calculate it from ground...
    public const int SIZEOF_TEXUTRE_RGBA_U8C4_640x480 = 4 * sizeof(byte) * 640 * 480;

    // Cannot declare compile time constant as following in C#
    //public const int SIZEOF_TEXUTRE_RGBA_U8C4_640x480_2 = 4 * PixelType._8UC4.PixelSize() * 640 * 480;
}

public static class PixelTypeMethods
{
    public static /*constexpr*/ int PixelSize(this PixelType type)
    {
        int value = (int)type;
        int unit_size = value & 0xFF;
        int unit_count = (value & 0xFF00) >> 8;
        return unit_count * unit_size;
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum PixelType
{
    RGBA_8UC4 = RGBA | _8U | _C4,

    /////////////////////////
    RGBA = 1 << 16,

    /////////////////////////
    _8UC4 = _8U | _C4,

    /////////////////////////
    _C4 = 4  << 8,

    /////////////////////////
    _8U = sizeof(byte)
}
```

Comment: Is this another way of asking if C# has an equivalents to constexpr in C++11?

Answer (score 6):

To declare a constant (`const`) the value assigned needs to be a compile time constant. Calling a method automatically makes it not a compile time constant.

The alternative is to use `static readonly`:

```
public static readonly int SIZEOF_TEXUTRE_RGBA_U8C4_640x480_2 =
    4 * PixelType._8UC4.PixelSize() * 640 * 480;
```

Comment: I have to make SIZEOF_TEXUTRE_RGBA_U8C4_640x480_2 be 'const' since furture code requires compile time constant... 'readonly' broadcasts run time depends... Is it a C# language limitation -- unable to declare a compile time const function? Is there any workaround ?

Comment: @Raymond: Why does future code require a compile time constant?

Comment: @Raymond: I have the feeling you don't really understand what *compile time constant* actually means. It means that the value is known to the compiler. It further means that the constant declaration will completely vanish from the generated IL code as the value of the constant is inlined wherever it is used. The C# compiler doesn't execute the code of the program it currently is compiling, so it is impossible to declare methods as compile time constant.

Comment: I clear the compile time means, but I do want to simplify 'const' declaration in my sample code. SIZEOF_TEXUTRE_RGBA_U8C4_640x480_2 is simply a const calculate from other const. The 'calculate formula' is simple. I want to 'reuse' the formula.

Comment: @Raymond: You can't. There is no preprocessor in C# and there also is no support for real [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

Comment: Another way to think of it; the [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) can execute arbitrary `static` code (and `public static readonly int x = 20` is just a syntactic sugar replacement for a static constructor -- the static constructor is called at runtime, not compile time), but the compiler can't run code because the C# compiler doesn't have a preprocessor like a C family language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate to do this, you can do it using a [source generator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview)

The source generator can generate code mid-compilation which contains your constant. Then, using the `partial` keyword, you can splice together generated code and code that you wrote.